# How to stop a current ajax connection and start a new one?

Tags: jquery, ajax, load, chat

i have a chat box that will load new messages using ajax on my content page and it will listen for new ones every 20s. It is working. However, right now i have another link that will allow a user to load previous messages. And that button does not seem to work even though i have already done a clearTimeout() on the existing ajax function. any idea why?

My scripts:

```
   //for loading previous messages

    var timer;       

    $('#getoldmessages').click(function() {

        $("#workroom_boxes_chatpast").html('<img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/ui-anim_basic_16x16.gif"/>&nbsp; Loading...');
        $.ajax({
            url: "/messages/{{ chat.key.id }}",
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                $("#chatcontent").html(html);
                $("#workroom_boxes_chatpast").html('Loaded');
            }
        });
                    clearTimeout(timer);

});      



   //for new messages

function updateMsg() {
$.ajax({
url: "/recent/messages/{{ chat.key.id }}",
cache: false,
success: function(html){
$("#chatcontent").html(html);
}
});
//alert('repeating');
t = setTimeout(updateMsg, 20000);
}
updateMsg();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout(this, 20000);` is broken, `this` refers to a jquery object in that context, not a function. Check your javascript console and you'll see an error.

You don't need to `clearTimeout` to make a separate ajax call. Moreover, your call might not work because you're referring to the variable `timer` which has the timeout id from the **first** call to `setTimeout`, but any successive call will return a new id. So you need to add in your `updateMsg` the variable assignment: `timer = setTimeout(updateMsg,20000);`.

If your initial code is being executed in a `$()` block separate from `updateMsg`, then timer will only be visible in that block and changing that in `updateMsg` won't have an effect, another problem. If so, either make `timer` global, or attach it to a global object, or put `updateMsg` in that `$()` block.

Lastly, you should be using `setInterval` anyway, instead of recalling `setTimeout` every time, that's what it is made for.

Comment: i wish to stop the setTimeout(updateMsg,20000) but my clearTimeout(t) doesnt seem to work...i have a set a var t; as global and within updateMsg(), i have assign t = setTimeout(updateMsg,20000) as well. What else should i do to get it work?

Comment: @pivotal, it looks like you're assigning `t=setTimeout(...);` but then calling `clearTimeout(timer)`, you should use either `t` or `timer` consistently.